# vue-material localized theme to avoid conflict

Tags: vue.js, vue-material

Running a **vuejs** application **as component of a website**, using **vue-material theming css** create conflict with existing css.

By default, vue-material add a class on html `<html class="md-theme-default">` to apply its style but I am trying to change that by only applying on a specific DOM element which should be my vue app.

Coming from **material-ui**, what I am looking for is the equivalent of [`<ThemeProvider>` component](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/).

Also, I **only import a few components** doing the following:

```
import { MdTabs, MdRadio } from "vue-material/dist/components";
import "vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css";
import "./theme.scss";

Vue.use(MdRadio);
Vue.use(MdTabs);
```

**Theme.scss** redefine colors to match my theme.

```
@import "./variables";
@import "~vue-material/dist/theme/engine"; // Import the theme engine

@include md-register-theme("default", (
  primary: $purple,
  accent: $purple
));

@import "~vue-material/dist/theme/all"; // Apply the theme
```

I am using **single .vue files** with the following template synthax:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <md-radio v-model="radio" :value="objA">20€ / an</md-radio>
    <md-radio v-model="radio" :value="objB">2€ / mois</md-radio>
  </div>
</template>
```